# How load a vectorSource without XHR

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Using the latest version of Openlayers, `4.3.1`, i set a vector source as follows:

```
this.vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      url: `../assets/data/file.json`,
      format: new ol.format.TopoJSON()
    });

    this.vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: this.vectorSource,
      style: this.style
    });
```

But the file, in some cases, needed a previous treatement through other function.

How i can load the `file.json`, treat him and use in `ol.source.vector`?

I trying with a response ajax too, where `dataSource` variable is a response from ajax call to same `URL` in the first example `../assets/data/file.json`

```
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.TopoJSON()).readFeatures(dataSource)
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily. Configure the `ol.source.Vector` without a URL. Instead, you can load your json yourself and turn it into an object with

```
var json = JSON.parse(dataSource);
```

Then modify the JSON object, and finally call

```
var features = new ol.format.TopoJSON().readFeatures(dataSource,
    {featureProjection: view.getProjection()});
vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
```

Note the `featureProjection` option, which is required unless your view has the same projection as your data source.

Comment: But in the latest version, the [`readFeatures`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.TopoJSON.html#readFeatures) method has only one arguments

Comment: That's not true. See http://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.2/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#readFeatures.